# Python - Read a GPS through I2C? How would I do this?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gps, raspberry-pi3, i2c

I'm trying to read data from [this GPS](https://shop.watterott.com/CAM-M8Q-Breakout-Multi-GNSS-Module-GPS-QZSS-GLONASS-BeiDou-Galileo) through python. This GPS is hooked up to my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ via I2C. I need to use I2C communication, as my serial ports are going to be used by a different device.

So far my endless googling has brought me nowhere. I can't seem to find any python libraries that will let me do this. Can anyone here help me get started? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, we are here to help you. Can you please elaborate full things to me

Comment: @Suman Sure thing! What other information do you need :)

Comment: can we connect so we can understand better

Comment: @Suman. I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by connect? We are connected, here on stackoverflow :)

Comment: It tells you on page 12 of the data sheet https://learn.watterott.com/sensors/cam-m8q/cam-m8.pdf